# Page load on click of link, does not work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a side bar, in which there is a link to account page. Now on the click of the account in that sidebar, the regarding javascript is not executing, how ever if I reload the page it's executing properly. I can't understand the behaviour. Can anyone help me understand the issue

```
$(document).on("ready page:load",function(){

    makeProfile();

});




function makeProfile(){

        $('#profile-form').hide();

        $('.profile-edit').on("click",function(e){


            // if they click on edit, show the form, other wise show the divs
          if($('.profile-edit').text() == "Edit"){
            $('.profile-edit').text("Save");
            $('.profile-details').hide();
            $('#profile-form').show();
          }else{

                $('.submit-hidden').click();

          }

        });
}
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML that it's trying work with? also what if you switch out to `$(document).ready(function() {
makeProfile();
});`

This way you're using jQuerys document ready instead of the 'on' listener.

Comment: Actually if we reload the page, that means on ready executes at that time it is executing fine. But the problem is with the turbo links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `turbolinks:load`

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load",function(){

    makeProfile();

});
```